# YAML parsing with comments for doc purpose

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I need to add comments on YAML to build automatically a doc of my YAML files, as like docstrings do for Python.

So I'm looking for a parser in python that is able to:

- respect order of objects
- include comments

My research point me to ruamel.yaml. But unless than I did not get every thing, it does not allow to access YAML object when loaded with the comments. It only allows to dump that comments as it was during the load.

Do you know, what could answer my needs?

Comment: Well, a YAML file is just a text file, with some indentation.  Parse it as a text file and you're good to go.

Comment: @ryguy72 Comments are introduced in YAML by whitespace followed by `#`, but this sequence can occur as part of a scalar, e.g. if that scalar is quoted, or a multiline scalar. So extracting the comments, and just the comments is not as trivial as you make it sound.

Answer (score 2):

In `ruamel.yaml`, the `YAML()` instance only keeps the information to
load resp. dump your YAML document. *It does not allow you access to
the comments, because it doesn't store them on the instance*.

As you indicated, `ruamel.yaml` can dump the comments, so they have to
be somewhere, and indeed they are: attached to the object hierarchy
created by `YAML.load()`. And what you need to do is recursively walk
the data structure that you loaded to get the attached comments.

Something like the following can do that for the way comments currently are attached:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.tokens import CommentToken

yaml_str = """\
a:
  b:
  - elem1   # this is the first comment
  - elem2   # this is the second comment
  c:
    d: 42   # this is not the 42nd comment  
"""

def extract_from_token(tl):
    assert isinstance(tl, list)
    for t in tl:
        if t is None:
            continue
        yield t.start_mark.line, t.value

def get_yaml_comments(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if d.ca.comment is not None:
            for l, c in extract_from_token(d.ca.comment):
                yield l, c
        for key, val in d.items():
            for l, c in get_yaml_comments(val):
                yield l, c
            if key in d.ca.items:
                for l, c in extract_from_token(d.ca.items[key]):
                    yield l, c
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        if d.ca.comment is not None:
            for l, c in extract_from_token(d.ca.comment):
                yield l, c
        for idx, item in enumerate(d):
            for l, c in get_yaml_comments(item):
                yield l, c
            if idx in d.ca.items:
                for l, c in extract_from_token(d.ca.items[idx]):
                    yield l, c


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)

for line, comment in get_yaml_comments(data):
    print(f"{comment!r} ({line})")
```

which gives:

```
'# this is the first comment\n' (2)
'# this is the second comment\n' (3)
'# this is not the 42nd comment  \n' (5)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, and thanks for the response. It does what you say, it print out comments of a yaml string. But what I'm looking is slightly different. I want to extract comments and yaml part. I don't specially want to extract embedded comment in the structure. So I would like to end up with a list [comment, yaml, comment, yaml...]. I don't undertand why is is so complicated to do so, and why is not docummented.

Comment: You should update your question, as what you describe in your comment is completely unclear from your post. Of course I cannot document how to do what every single person (and apparently very few others) in the world wants to do with the press of one button, but feel free to implement that when you think it is easy. Just provide a PR, including the documentation.

Comment: I have a good idea on how to get what you describe in your comment, but since I might make it to complicated, I'll wait for you to come up with a PR for the simple solution yourself.

Comment: lol Anthon... No, I got angry about myself not to be able to do what I wanted, based on your advices. It was nothing about your solution. What I wanted to say is that it is a pitty that ruamel module does not provide easier method for that.

Answer (score 0):

just updated the example, permit to better understand the additionals ruamel parsing, and recursive descente :

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.tokens import CommentToken

yaml_str = """\
# comment above a
a: # comment on a
  # comment above b key
  b: # comment on b
  # comment inside b in list
  - elem1   # this is the first comment
  - elem2   # this is the second comment
  c: # comment on c
    d: 42   # this is not the 42nd comment  
"""

def extract_from_token(tl):
    assert isinstance(tl, list)
    for t in tl:
        if t is None:
            continue
        if isinstance(t, list):
            for r in t:
                yield r.start_mark.line, r.value
        else:
            yield t.start_mark.line, t.value

def get_yaml_comments(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if d.ca.comment is not None:
            for l, c in extract_from_token(d.ca.comment):
                yield l, c, d
        for key, val in d.items():
            for l, c , val in get_yaml_comments(val):
                yield l, c, val
            if key in d.ca.items:
                for l, c in extract_from_token(d.ca.items[key]):
                    yield l, c, key
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        if d.ca.comment is not None:
            for l, c in extract_from_token(d.ca.comment):
                yield l, c, d
        for idx, item in enumerate(d):
            for l, c, item in get_yaml_comments(item):
                yield l, c, item
            if idx in d.ca.items:
                for l, c in extract_from_token(d.ca.items[idx]):
                    yield l, c, item


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)

for line, comment, item in get_yaml_comments(data):
    print(f"{comment!r} ({line}) on {item}")
```

this output :

```
'# comment above a\n' (0) on {'a': {'b': ['elem1', 'elem2'], 'c': {'d': 42}}}
'# comment on a\n  # comment above b key\n' (1) on {'b': ['elem1', 'elem2'], 'c': {'d': 42}}
'# comment on b\n  # comment inside b in list\n' (3) on ['elem1', 'elem2']
'# this is the first comment\n' (5) on elem1
'# this is the second comment\n' (6) on elem2
'# comment on b\n  # comment inside b in list\n' (3) on b
'# comment on c\n' (7) on {'d': 42}
'# this is not the 42nd comment  \n' (8) on d
'# comment on c\n' (7) on c
'# comment on a\n  # comment above b key\n' (1) on a
```